# Exporting specific columns from an access table to excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, export

i am looking to export a certain access table to excel but i don't want all the columns to be exported but two. I tried following code for a general export table but it doesn't fulfil the requirement:

```
UserName = Environ("Username")
filepath = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Desktop\"
FileName = "Analysis Outcome - " & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
destination = filepath & FileName
tablename = "SelectedMonth"

Need some logic here to select only two columns viz. 'Employee Name' and 'Status' from the 
table - SelectedMonth

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tablename, destination
```

Comment: Create a query that has the two columns in it that you want, and export that instead. In addition, a query allows you to specify a sort order, whereas in a table there is no real sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a query (`SELECT SelectedMonth.[Employee Name], SelectedMonth.[Status] FROM SelectedMonth;`) and take it as the source for your export.